Is It safe to move external header file in clang include directory in mac
In my mac system I have installed both gnu-gcc, gnu-g++ and apple-clang, apple-clang++ through home brew but as time. I am some header files are not available in apple-clang but in gnu-gcc there are.
I am thinking to move some header file like bits/stdc++.h:
Example
cp "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0/include/c++/14/bits/stdc++.h" "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/bits/stdc++.h"


-I /the/path/of/your/included/somthing.h is a mistake; -I specifies a directory to search for files, not a file to include, and similarly for -L. And the output switch is -o, not -0.

^That. Please provide an actual [mre], instead of some lookalike.

Please don't change your question after receiving an answer. Post a new question instead.

There are multiple solutions for this. Rather than putting your files in directories that Clang is already searching, it may be better to tell Clang to search additional directories that you specify. (Depending on how your Clang was built, the directories it searches by default may be those of, say, your Xcode installation, and updating the installation in the future might overwrite any files you add to it. You want your files in a separate area controlled by you.)
The easiest way might be to set the environment variables C_INCLUDE_PATH, CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH, and LIBRARY_PATH to paths to directories containing C header files, C++ header files, and library files.
Generally, this should be done only as a convenience for simple direct user command-line builds. When setting up a project, you want it built correctly, using its own specifications of paths to use, and not taking paths from the user’s environment. To this end, another simple solution is to set up your own shell script which passes its arguments to clang along additional switches specifying header and library search paths. This method also lets you set other switches, such as default warning options, the language variant to use, and optimization level. By using a shell script with your own custom name, it will not interfere with use of clang in other projects.
Clang also has methods of specifying configuration files.
